# linux root server: statistics

Tags: ubuntu, root

I have installed ubuntu server on my homeserver because I want to learn how to setup/manage a root server (before I buy one). On the root server I will host a website.

I want to know:

- which file from my webserver was downloaded the most
- the avarage cpu/ram usage
- and so on...

I just want some statistics. Is there any software you can recommend me or a book I should read?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CPU and RAM usage: http://munin-monitoring.org/

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the webalizer or awstat packages for hits and page views, or alternatively configure google analytics to track your visitors.